# How to display images from Giphy in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, giphy

The code bellow is pulling data from Giphy. I am trying to let the user search a term and display the images on the page. I currently have one image displaying and it is creating a cookie trail of buttons that allow the user to go back and click images they have seen before. I need to loop through and display one image for each image url returned from console.log(data). I can get the data to display the image urls in the console but not create a button for each. Any help is appreciated.

```
                <div class="wrapper">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div id="animalButtons"></div>

                            <form class="input-append">
                                <div id="field">
                                    <input class="input" id="formValueId" type="text" placeholder="Type something"/>
                                    <input type="button" class="myButton" value="Search" />
                                </div>
                            </form>

                            <div id="field1"></div>
                        <div id="searchResults"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>


          function buttonFeature(value){
              request.open('GET', 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&q='+value, true);
              request.send('GET', 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&q='+value, true);
          };


          document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
          $(document).ready(function() {

              $('.myButton').click(function(e) {
              var searchFeature = ($('#formValueId').val());
              request = new XMLHttpRequest;
              request.open('GET', 'http://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=dc6zaTOxFJmzC&q='+searchFeature, true);


              var next = 1;

              var searchFeature = ($('#formValueId').val());

              //console.log(searchFeature);

                e.preventDefault();
                var addto = "#field" + next;
                next = next + 1;
                var newIn = '<button id="newButton" value='+searchFeature+' onclick="buttonFeature(this.value)">'+searchFeature+'</button>';
                var newInput = $(newIn);
                $(addto).after(newInput);


              request.onload = function() {
                for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
                  data = JSON.parse(request.responseText).data[i].images.fixed_height.url;
                  console.log(data);
                  document.getElementById("searchResults").innerHTML = '<center><img src = "'+data+'"  title="GIF via Giphy"></center><br>';
                }
              };
              request.onerror = function() {
                console.log('connection error');
              };
              request.send();
              });
            });
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of innerHTML that was replacing the image every time it looped I used Jquery like this $("#searchResults").append(' Rating: '+rating+'');